# jQuery appending & prepending some texts to selected words on textarea

Tags: jquery, select, focus, textarea

I have a textarea and one button above this textarea. I want to select a word(s) in this textarea and prepend + append some signs to selected word(s).

For example:

hello -> (hello) // i want to prepend "(" and append ")" when click one button above or below textarea. But i don't know how to do it with selected words?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend that you use: [jQuery - fieldSelection](https://github.com/localhost/jquery-fieldselection)

It has the functions: `getSelection()` and `replaceSelection(text)`

So you could do this:

```
var before = $(this).getSelection();
$(this).replaceSelection(prepend + before + append);
```